# Gmail Account came from where?

Tags: gmail

Google News is my Homepage.  I use the postage stamp / verizon.net for my mail.  When I log onto my homepage, my address is listed as wiliamnbenoit@gmail in the upper right-hand corner. Notice that william is spelled wrong.

I have never used Gmail ever ! How do I get rid of that and sign in to my real email address of williamnbenoit@verizon.net ?

I am using Google Plus with my Google account, and do not want to start all over again (2 years of building it up)by losing all of my Google Plus information.

Somehow, Google Plus is attached to Gmail, and I have  an address that I did not create , nor is my name spelled correctly in it.

What can I do to reset my verizon address into Google and still use Google Plus.  I do not even want a Gmail account...

Comment: What is it you're asking exactly? Where your account came from? How to change email address on Google+?

By the way, William isn't spelled wrong, your username here on Stack Exchange is the same, just with some spaces. If you add spaces to the gmail it would be "william n benoit".

Answer (score 2):

Is `wiliamnbenoit` your Google+ account name? `wiliamnbenoit@gmail` is thus your full Google sign-in name, even if you never use it for email. Google+ is (I think always) tied to some Google login, which could be @gmail.com or at a "Google apps for your domain" domain.

The top of these Google pages simply show what your current Google login is.

Google login is independent of your Verizon email. It should not interfere in any way, besides being a bit confusing here.

You don't need to use this Gmail account. If you want to, you could log into it once and use Settings to make it forward any incoming mail to your Verizon account.